# Printers Available in India That Work With Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, printing

can anyone come up with multifunction laser printers available in India that work with Ubuntu 12.04? I'm asking because on most websites, I can't seem to find the models which are available on Indian markets/shopping websites. I know that sometimes that does happen, because new models replace old ones at a delayed schedule here.

Comment: I don't know which specific printers are available in India. However, HP printers usually have great Linux support. That means they work with Ubuntu without much trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Best and safest, any HP you will buy in India or elsewhere will work with Ubuntu, be it their multi function, stand alone or laser, thats how good HP support for open source is. Epson has also improved but its still patchy, so is Canon.

Answer (score 0):

I would ask this on an Ubuntu site that is related to India. As an example: http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=389 You are guaranteed to find people from India there with specific local knowledge.

Also likely to be able of use:

- IRC: `#ubuntu-in @ irc.freenode.net`
- Mailing List: https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-in

But I agree with user68186 in comment: HP has always worked for me.

Comment: I would have made it a comment is it was not that long. So no upvoting please since this is more than likely to get closed ;)